# Concise Swift assertion for Bool? || Bool?

Tags: swift, swift3, assertions, conditional-operator

Can I formulate a concise expression in Swift for asserting that the activity indicator of one of two view controllers is animating. The expression may assume that either `vc1` or `vc2` is distinct from `nil`.

The following does not quite work, presumably because it is of the form `Bool? || Bool?` instead of `Bool || Bool`:

```
assert(vc1?.activityIndicator.isAnimating ||
       v22?.activityIndicator.isAnimating)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` still works for optionals, so you could do something like this:

```
assert(vc1?.activityIndicator.isAnimating == true ||
       v22?.activityIndicator.isAnimating == true)
```